# How can I resize the resolution so the display isn't clipped?

Tags: nvidia, display, hdmi, display-resolution

so I have a RCA tv that I use as a monitor, it has no option to adjust the resolution since I connect through HDMI so it greys out "PC Settings", I downloaded `Nvidia Xserver settings` and it helped a bit, although I wasn't able to make the resolution fit properly, I've been trying by adjusting it through XServer but the end results are always clipped, here's an approximate of how my screen looks like, I'd really appreciate if you could help me figure out why does this happen.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I'm using Underscan in Nvidia Xserver settings, while not perfect, at least it minimizes the stuff cut from the display to an acceptable minimum.